# How do you find a peak rate in time series?

Tags: time-series

I have a series of timestamps, and I would like to know what's the maximum hourly rate of the event that these timestamps represent. You can generalize this to any units. I'm looking for a window (interval) of a certain size that contains most of these values. The obvious approach is to divide the set by this interval and then pick the one with most values. This is however imprecise, especially if the peak is near the limits of interval. Is there some better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic programming.  Since a peak rate is only ever achieved at an event, you only have to check the rate at each event.  If the window is a fixed length of time, you keep a queue of events within the window.  For each event, add the event to your queue, and remove events that are no longer within the window.  Your peak rate is the maximum size of the queue.

Comment: Yup, I did just that, friend of mine told me I could call this _sliding window approach_ :P

Comment: The term 'events' seems better suited here than 'time series'. An ad hoc solution is fitting a continuously density, after conversion of the timestamps into numeric values. For instance the 'density' R function
can be of some help. The idea is that events occur at random times which need smoothing.

Many kind of statistical models can be used to describe events with possibly trend, seasonality, exogenous effects. One of these is the non-homogenous Poisson point process.